# .command file on macOS executes code different than manually typing the script in terminal. Why?

Tags: macos, terminal, path, python-3.11

I am working on, Project: Multi-Clipboard Automatic Messages from Automate the Boring Stuff. I am using MacOS. The issue I am facing is when I try and execute the .command file in spotlight, I am successful in creating the path and returning the code file in the terminal. Though once executed, it only brings up the initial prompt of the code, and in the terminal it returns, [process completed]. At this point I no longer can enter the keyphrase that would return the phrase txt I'm looking for, which is the codes function.

In my mclip.command shell file, I have this entered.

`python3 /Users/maxhatter/dev/mclip.py`

Here is the terminal message after calling the file:

```
/Users/maxhatter/commands/mclip.command ; exit;
➜  ~ /Users/maxhatter/commands/mclip.command ; 
exit;
Usage: python mclip.py [keyphrase] - copy phrase 
text

Saving session...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Though, when I manually enter into the terminal the same path that's in the .command file. I get this:

```
➜  ~ python3 /Users/maxhatter/dev/mclip.py              
Usage: python mclip.py [keyphrase] - copy phrase 
text
➜  ~ python3 /Users/maxhatter/dev/mclip.py busy
Text for busy copied to clipboard.
➜  ~ Sorry, can we do this later this week or next 
week?
```

You see I get the same, `Usage: python mclip.py [keyphrase] - copy phrase text`, but I can also enter the path again with the keyphrase to copy the text to the clipboard, and then just paste.

Why when using the .command file, the code just ends and I can't enter anymore?

If you need to try an recreate my problem, here is the multi-clipboard program:

```
#! python3
#mclip.py - A multi-clipboard program.

TEXT = {'agree': """Yes, I agree. That sounds fine to me.""",
     'busy': """Sorry, can we do this later this week or next week?""",
     'upsell': """Would you consider making this a monthly donation?"""}

import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: python mclip.py [keyphrase] - copy phrase text')
    sys.exit()

keyphrase = sys.argv[1]   #first command line arg is the keyphrase

if keyphrase in TEXT:
    pyperclip.copy(TEXT[keyphrase])
    print('Text for ' + keyphrase + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no text for ' + keyphrase)
```

I originally saved the code for the .command file with TextEdit, but switched to saving the file with VS Code, thinking it would be a better file editor. Received the same results.

I have made sure the shell script is executable by running `chmod u+x mclip.command` in the terminal. I believe this worked properly.

In my computers terminal, I have entered the path, `python3 /Users/maxhatter/dev/mclip.py`. It found the code file as expected and returned the initial prompt. I then entered the path followed by the key word, `python3 /Users/maxhatter/dev/mclip.py busy`. It also executed as expected and returned the matching string value. The code works when executing full path each time.

I entered my mclip.command file with this script,
`python3 /Users/maxhatter/dev/mclip.py`, in spotlight expecting the code to run properly, but I receive the issue as explained in the details of my problem section above.

Comment: Can you reformat the examples in in [code block format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)? It's very hard to figure out what's going on as they are now. But it looks like in the one where it works, you actually run the script twice, passing arguments the second time. Is that correct? If so, that's the problem: running it via a .command script only runs it once, and doesn't let you enter arguments. If you want it to be useful as a .command, the script will need to read input, rather than expecting arguments.

Comment: Did I reformat that correctly?

Comment: Ok. I am understanding how the .command file operates. The script that needs to read input, would that be the script in the .command file? Or the script in the program file? My guess is the program script?

Comment: Much better; see answer for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.command files cannot take command-line arguments, but your mclip.py current requires one. To make it usable as a .command, it'll need to read input as it runs. This could be done either in the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'Keyword: ' keyword
python3 /Users/maxhatter/dev/mclip.py "$keyword"
```

or in the python script:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    keyphrase = sys.argv[1]   #first command line arg is the keyphrase
elif len(sys.argv) == 1:
    keyphrase = input('Keyphrase: ')
else:
    print('Usage: python mclip.py [keyphrase] - copy phrase text')
    sys.exit()
```

If it's done in the python script, the shell script becomes unnecessary -- you could just give the python script a .command extension, fix its shebang line (it should be either `#!/usr/bin/python3` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, not just `#! python3`), and make it executable (`chmod +x /path/to/mclip.command`). The only reason the shell script was needed in the first place was to tell the system to run the python script with `python3`, and that's what shebang lines are for.

Comment: Adding an `input()` to the python script was very helpful, and allows me to enter a key word before the session ends. 
I also experience that whether or not I have the shebang in the .command file, it executes just the same. I do get different results when I input the shebang incorrectly. Why does it seem to not matter to not have it at all?

Comment: I also experience that whether or not I have the shebang in the .command file, it works just the same. If I enter the shebang incorrectly it does make a difference. Why does it seem to not matter if it's there at all? (also, the read keyword script you provided for the .command file didn't work for me. I'd still like to figure out how to make that work through the .command file)

Comment: If there's no shebang in a script, the system will generally default to running it with /bin/sh, which is not quite the same as /bin/bash (on some OSes it's a less powerful shell, but on macOS it's actually bash but with some features disabled). You can sometimes get away without a shebang, but it's safer to have one. As for the shell script not working: did it give an error message? How exactly did it fail?

Comment: Well it didn't fail. That script, it seems unless I'm doing it wrong, requires me to put the key word into the shell script. I need to be able to enter any of the key words from my python script when prompted.

Comment: @MaxHatter The shell script I gave above should do that. The `read` command reads the keyword as input, then `"$keyword"` passes it as an argument to the python script.

Comment: Here is message from using shell script: ```/Users/maxhatter/commands/mclip.command ; exit;                                 
➜  ~ /Users/maxhatter/commands/mclip.command ; exit;
/Users/maxhatter/commands/mclip.command:read:2: -p: no coprocess
There is no text for 

Saving session...completed.

[Process completed]```

Comment: @MaxHatter That error message indicates the script is running under zsh rather than bash; did you include the shebang line?

Comment: Here is what I entered: `#!/bin/zsh
read -p 'Keyword: ' keyword  
python3 /Users/maxhatter/dev/mclip.py "$keyword"`. My computer automatically dowloaded python to zsh (zshell) and created the PATH there as well. I tried to transfer to bash, but it seems my computer likes to operate in zsh. To my knowledge I have had no issues, all other code works fine.

Comment: @MaxHatter zsh is the default *interactive* shell on recent versions of macOS, but that has no effect on what shell scripts are run under. bash is still there, and works fine. Programs like python are not shell-specific (however, if you installed a version of python other than the one that comes with the system, it might not be available unless run from an interactive shell -- but zsh vs bash won't matter here either).  Since this particular script was written with bash syntax, you *must* run it with bash (or rewrite it to use zsh syntax).

Comment: Thank you for all the help @GordonDavisson